# С# StreamReader аналог pop из Stack

Tags: c#, строки, файлы

Есть некий файл с текстом/данными, и есть `StreanReader`который уже связан с этим файлом. Мне нужно получать из файла n-символов из позиции x, и удалять все полученные символы из файла. что то около такого

файл с данными :

> я собрал 5 яблок и 3 сливы

Ожидаемый код

```
string text = reader.Pop(5); // "я соб"
```

оставшиеся данные в файле

> рал 5 яблок и 3 сливы

Есть ли уже встроенный функционал подобного типа, или же нужно ручками писать такое?

Comment: Удалить начало файла просто так не получится, вам придется файл перезаписать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого встроенного функционала в стандартных библиотеках .NET Framework нет. Возможно, есть third-party решения.

Сделайте свой метод.

По шагам:

1. Считайте данные

   ```
   string str = string.Empty;
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(*путь_к_файлу*)) 
   {
       str = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   ```
2. Модифицируйте их

   ```
   string result = string.Empty;
   result = str.Remove(0, count);
   ```

Где 0 - стартовая позиция, count - количество удаляемых символов.

3. Запишите

   ```
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(*путь_к_файлу*, false))
   {
        writer.Write(result);
   }
   ```

Обратите внимание, что второй параметр [конструктора StreamWriter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) как раз отвечает за перезапись файла